# Regex to match PHP Function definition

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching, editor

I need a regex string to match PHP Function definitions like:

`function anyname(any, number, of, params) {`

in editors like Geany or Notepad++ and insert a static text (ofcourse PHP Code) such as `var_dump(debug_backtrace());` inside the matched function definitions.

As I have to debug a very large PDF Class file of size around 1.24MB and having more than 60 function definitions.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Don't get why this question was downvoted ? It could be real help to developers for debugging n Live sites. Doesn't make sense in downvoting.

Comment: Well by debugging the class I meant I want to know which functions are being called when PDF class is instantiated and pdf is generated. For that first I have to put `var_dump(debug_backtrace)` in every function as I guess so "doing that quickly" was my intention behind the question, I couldn't test regex in live site so I asked this, if anyone had did this before.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
function\s+.*?\)\s*{
```

I did a rough test and it works on my Notepad++.

**EDIT**

If you need to replace these with the debug backtrace, do this:

Find:

```
function\s+(.*?)\)\s*{
```

Replace:

```
function \1\) {\nvar_dump\(debug_backtrace\(\)\);
```

Tested with Notepad++.

**Explanation:**

The regex itself is nothing too fancy. The `.*?` simply means "Match anything, ungreedy". It will match everything until it sees a closing bracket and stop.

During the find and replacement, the `.*?` is enclosed into a bracket, because we need to take this out as the texts we need to preserve, and then fill it up in the `\1` position in the replacement.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help out, it actually finds all the functions, but how can I replace the matching definition lines with lines themselves along with a newline and a new line added like `var_dump(debug_backtrace());` and all the rest of function code remains intact too ?

Comment: Also, please explain your answer in details too.

Comment: Yep done, Check out my answer again

Comment: Thanks a ton it did replace almost all functions, but some of them were still left out, I don't think why, those are as below: `function dec2alpha($valor,$toupper="true"){`, `function dec2roman($valor,$toupper=true){` does it has something to do with `=` or comma sign.

Comment: You can take example from fusion3k. His answer tries to match none or one or more spaces. The reason why these functions failed to be replaced is because there is no space between the closing bracket and opening curly bracket.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include white space matching as well.